# What's the name of this circuit?

Tags: voltage, bjt, voltage-divider

[image: new circuit:]

As i said in the title what's the name of that circuit and any characteristic for it?

Comment: I'm assuming ground is at the node that R1 and R2 are connected to ?

Comment: The name of this circuit, as it is drawn, is "BS".

Comment: Are you sure you've drawn that correctly? R2 and R3 look wrong - they just connect Vcc and ground.  I'd expect them to be connected to the base of the transistor.

Comment: really sorry i edited it. result of 3 days without sleeping.

Comment: If you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar you can save your schematic inline with the post and it is editable and we can copy it. No need for screengrabs and no grid. Double-click the components to set their values. Use GND symbols in the appropriate places. Drag connections to get the connection dots where required. Label the inputs and outputs using the NODE symbol. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: It would be a (poorly designed) common emitter amplifier if C2 did not short the output to ground.

Comment: I think C2 should be connected across R1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit is usually referred to as a common emitter voltage amplifier. However the values of the resistors are somewhat unusual.  R2 and R3, which set the bias of the transistor, are usually in the kilohm range. With R1 and R4 equal, the voltage gain of the circuit will be close to one. Capacitor C2 at the output will limit the useful frequency range of the circuit to less than 2 kHz.

Comment: ... and if I'm not mistaken, if you try to amplify something with an amplitude over 0.7 V, the transistor will saturate at the peaks and the output will be distorted.

Comment: I am pretty sure that C2 should be in parallel to R1 - and, as a consequence, the voltage gain will be considerably > 1.

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed look as if you have (mis)drawn a single transistor small signal amplifier in a form that is often presented to students, called a "common emitter".

In this circuit, the resistor R1 from the emitter to ground helps the DC biasing stability (because it provides negative feedback), but also reduces the AC gain. Very often a largish capacitor is placed from the emitter to ground, which effectively removes that feedback at the frequencies of interest, and improves gain.

Could it be that C2 was intended to play this role? From where did you get this circuit? C2 as you drew it causes the amplifier to drive a purely capacitive load, which I doubt it would much like.

Also (as the previous commenter stated) the resistors seem very low. They do depend a bit on the value of Vcc, usually somewhere in the 10-20V range, and then they are generally a few kilohms each, and operating currents are in the low mA.

(R2 and R3 set the DC bias point, while R4 is the load resistor which mostly determines voltage gain, by the way.)